# iOS beta -- unable to vote to close

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, ios-app

I was using the app and wanted to vote to close.  I was unable to do so, choosing vote immediately popped up a modal box saying that there was no reason.

> [image: voting to close]

and then:

> [image: error message]

Comment: Just a suggestion - I believe this is a generic error message for "can't vote to close." Is it possible you'd voted already, or the question was already closed? I'm not having any problems closing at the moment.

Comment: @Chris: could be, the question now shows as put on hold, with a vote by me...

Comment: If you go to your profile -> activity -> votes -> closure, and hover over the date for this close vote, you can see the time the vote was made. These screenshots show 9:09pm - would be one way to check if the two are related.

Comment: @Chris: not from within the app...I'll see what Safari lets me do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a little better in 1.4.3.3.

This error message appeared because either the question was closed or you already voted to close it, so I'm updating the error message to say just that:

> **No options found**
>
> Could not find any close options for this question.  You may have already voted to close this question or it may have been closed by other users.

It would be nice to be able to cancel or change your close vote from the app, but that's a topic for another feature-request.